# Reading GIC ID IRQ on Rk3328

Tags: operating-system, arm, irq

I am working on my OS bare-metal for my rk3328 tvbox. I am just write the code for irq handler but I have a problem reading the ID's IRQ occurred I am reading always 0 on ICCIAR register. Thanks for any help

Comment: Could you read any other registers from GIC that gives you a proper verifiable value.

Comment: Yes, I am using Control Register for Distributor and Cpu interfaces and them are working

Comment: I don't remember details that was a while ago I worked with that, but some GIC registers available from secure state only (or should be given special permission to be available from non-secure state). That secure/non-secure access might be playing. Out of head I could not say if accessing secure register from non-secure state would throw exception or just gives zeroes.

Comment: ...I have also many exceptions u may be  right  Do u have some code for that? Thanks for answer